# Make Scanner accept 1 or 2 inputs

Tags: java

Am currently learning Java and need to test a program that can accept one or two inputs using Scanner. In short, I need to be able to input only one number or two and have the program process either of the two cases. The problem is using `hasNext()`, I can't get the program to process only one number, it always waits until I enter two. How can I get around this? This is the method that is supposed to handle enter 1 or 2 numbers.

```java
private static void promptRequest() {
        System.out.print("Enter a request: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        long firstNumber = 0;
        long secondNumber = 0;
        try {
            firstNumber = sc.nextLong();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("First number is not a valid number");
            promptRequest();
        }
        if (sc.hasNext()) {
            try {
                secondNumber = sc.nextLong();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Second number is not a valid number");
                promptRequest();
            }
            processTwoNumbers(firstNumber, secondNumber);
        } else {
            processOneNumber(firstNumber);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use Scanner nextLine to read the entire input and split the numbers before parsing.

Comment: @josejuan I just want to be able to enter 1 number, hit enter, have it call the `processOneNumber` function with that number or enter two separate by a space and have it call the `processToNumber()` function with those two numbers

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc so are you saying I should read the input as a string, use split to turn it into an array, and then check if the array is 1 or 2 length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading from `stdin` then, infinite input characters are available from the **User Keyboard** :) that is why `hasNext` is always true (not to be confused with end-of-input values like `Ctrl+D`).

Decouple your job from a specific input stream (the `stdin`), for example, supose we will read all numbers as long as their sum is less than 100:

```
static void doJobWith(InputStream input) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(input);

    List<Long> xs = new ArrayList<>();

    while(s.hasNext() && xs.stream().mapToLong(x -> x).sum() < 100)
        xs.add(s.nextLong());

    System.out.printf("Input list: %s%n", xs.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(joining(", ")));
    System.out.printf("With sum: %d%n", xs.stream().mapToLong(x -> x).sum());
}
```

now, we can test with different inputs

```
List<String> examples = asList(
        "34",
        "34\n56\n23\n44\n45"
);

for(String example: examples)
    doJobWith(new ByteArrayInputStream(example.getBytes(UTF_8)));
```

with output

```
Input list: 34
With sum: 34

Input list: 34, 56, 23
With sum: 113
```

in the first example, although the sum is less than 100, the only number has been read. And, on the contrary, in the second example, although there were more numbers to be read, we have not done so because they already add up to 100.

(Complete code, change your package name)

```
package ...;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;

public class ScannerTest {

    static void doJobWith(InputStream input) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(input);

        List<Long> xs = new ArrayList<>();

        while (s.hasNext() && xs.stream().mapToLong(x -> x).sum() < 100)
            xs.add(s.nextLong());

        System.out.printf("Input list: %s%n", xs.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(joining(", ")));
        System.out.printf("With sum: %d%n", xs.stream().mapToLong(x -> x).sum());
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {

        List<String> examples = asList(
                "34",
                "34\n56\n23\n44\n45"
        );

        for (String example : examples)
            doJobWith(new ByteArrayInputStream(example.getBytes(UTF_8)));

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's a lot to take in since most of this code you used looks new to me but I will study it and see how it works. I am, although, getting an error from the `joining()` function/method you used inside the collect() method.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've updated with the full code.